# How to pass NSString Value from one method to another method on button addTarget method?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

How can I pass an NSString object as an argument to another method by using UIButton addTarget:

Here is my code:

```
 - (void)vision:(PBJVision *)vision capturedVideo:(NSDictionary *)videoDict error:(NSError *)error
{

    _recording = NO;

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"encounted an error in video capture (%@)", error);
        return;
    }


    _currentVideo = videoDict;

    NSString *videoPath = [_currentVideo  objectForKey:PBJVisionVideoPathKey];
    NSLog(@"string = %@",videoPath);



UIButton *ok = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    ok.frame = CGRectMake(95, 3, 50, 30);
    [ok setTitle:@"OK" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [ok addTarget:self action:@selector(okwindow:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [customview addSubview:ok];

}
```

How do I pass string value as a parameter for addTarget:

Please give any suggestions as well as a solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you want access to the videoPath string in the okwindow: method?  It's not done by passing state through the button.  Buttons are for collecting touch events.

Instead, change the state of your view controller by adding a property...

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *videoPath;
```

setting it when you get the string...

```
NSString *videoPath = [_currentVideo  objectForKey:PBJVisionVideoPathKey];
NSLog(@"string = %@",videoPath);
self.videoPath = videoPath;
```

and accessing it when the user presses the button...

```
- (void)okwindow:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"I still have the string = %@",self.videoPath);
}
```

Comment: I need one more help from you. Please watch this link and give some suggestion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706393/repeatmode-doesnt-work-in-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller